# Click Function Event Test based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, testing, qunit

How to check whether the click function is opening in correct target and the URL is not broken.
I used the below jQuery code for opening a link in a target canvas position, how to do the same as Qunit testing

```
$(".class_name").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#ad_id").attr({
        src: $(this).attr("href")
    });
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: How do you define "proper target" apart by the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuerys [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method, which simulates an event:

```
$(".class_name").trigger('click');
```

and then check if the src attribute of `$("#ad_id")` is your expected value.

Answer (score 0):

u can strip anchor with this variable

```
var anchor = document.location.hash;
```

and check whats left behind. example

```
$(".class_name").click(function(){
   var anchor = document.location.hash;
   if ( anchor === '#ad_id' ) {
     alert('ok');
   }else{ alert('not ok');}
});
```